# Cities Daylight saving time database

Tags: android, ios, database, timezone, dst

I am trying to get a database with cities and it's corresponding timezone including daylight saving time but I cannot find it.

I am making an `iOS` and `Android` application where a user can choose from which city he or she is and represents the time but for that I need the data to calculate the right time.

My current solution is to use the `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` (ID's are same for `Android`) but I discovered that there are a lot of cities missing such as Beijing and Abu Dhabi. Anyone any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here we can do one thing. Set a button in your app and add the below code in the button's action. So u can get the present date and time of their location.And the u can save the information by hitting your api(webservice of app).
-----------------------------------code----------------------------------

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000'Z'"];

NSString *iso8601String = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self];
```

(Nj)